# How to display selective fields in JSON to ng2-charts in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng2-charts

I just have below format of JSON and I just want to display only "date" as x-axis and "flow" as y axis and "percentage" should be display if I mouse hover to the bar chart.

I have below JSON:

```
{
   "testdata":[
      {
         "fail":3,
         "flow":"Checkout",
         "pass":20,
         "total":23,
         "percentage":80
      },
      {
         "fail":80,
         "flow":"add-cart",
         "pass":60,
         "total":140,
         "percentage":60
      },
      {
         "fail":20,
         "flow":"refund",
         "pass":59,
         "total":79,
         "percentage":80
      }
   ]
}
```

I can get the above payload while invoking the below method in component.ts file:

```
 public data:Array<String>=[]; 

 this.http.get(environmenthost.matrixFinder).subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this.data=data.testdata; // The above json is available in the data variable
   });
```

//The below I just tried for another requirement. I don't have any idea to build it for bar chart with above requirement.

I used ng2-charts to build the pie chart as like below:

```
            <canvas id="pie" baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [labels]="pieChartLabels"
            [colors]="pieChartColors"
            [chartType]="pieChartType"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Used below lines in component.ts file to feed the data to pie ng2-charts.

```
  public pieChartLabels: string[] = ['PayCreditWallet','Paypal','Google Pay','Amazon Pay'];
  public pieChartData: number[] = [1,2,3,4];
  public pieChartType: any = 'pie';

  public pieChartColors: Array < any > = [{
   backgroundColor: ['Violet', 'DodgerBlue', 'MediumSeaGreen','Tomato'],
   borderColor: ['rgba(135,206,250,1)', 'rgba(106,90,205,1)', 'rgba(148,159,177,1)'],
 }];
```

I can able to see the pie chart for the above data. Like I just wanna do bar chart with above JSON file and specific node as X and Y axis in bar chart.

I don't know how to display those data into bar chart. Can someone please help me to achieve this?